# getJSON info to Ruby each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I currently have a page which shows a vote count value, percentage value and the option string. I currently use Ruby variables to display this information and I'm currently working with a way to replace it with JSON information which I also want to auto update each 2-3 seconds.

I currently have a json file showing me the information I need but I can't figure out how to use the information in my Ruby each loop.

**Edit:**
I dont want to access the JSON info using ruby. I want to access it with Jquery. And I want to remove the Ruby variables and add Jquery code which will change the html information in the Span tags with the JSON information obtained by Jquery

JSON:

```
[
  {"option":"Godis","option_percentage":33,"vote_count":11},
  {"option":"Selleri","option_percentage":66,"vote_count":22}
]
```

If I think correctly I need to be able to get each hash option in each hash in an array. But I cant figuere out how I can do this and if it's the right way to do it. How should I get this working? How can I get and use the information I need using JQuerys getJSON() or ajax() functions?

Current way of showing the information:

```
<% @poll.options.each do |poll_option| %>      
  <% @vote_count_option = Vote.count(:poll_id => @poll.id, :vote => poll_option.id.to_i) %>
  <% @option_percentage = (@vote_count_option).percent_of(@votes_count) %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <p style="font-size: 16px">
        <span class="option"><%= poll_option.option %></span>
        <span style="float: right;">Votes: <%= @vote_count_option %> (<%= @option_percentage.to_i %>%)</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: <%= @option_percentage %>%"></div>
        </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want the variables to be replaced with the JSON information.

I'm using Sinatra's json extension and Datamapper.

Comment: you can't access a javascript json in ruby, your javascript is in the browser while your ruby is in the server, except I don't understand your question, you would be best doing this all in JS

Comment: I dont want to access the JSON info using ruby. I want to access it with Jquery. And I want to remove the Ruby variables and add Jquery code which will change the html information in the Span tags with the JSON information obtained by Jquery.

Comment: I think the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) might apply.